# Batch file IF statement syntax in WinSCP commands

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, syntax, winscp

I am trying to update a batch file that uses WinSCP to download files. But I am unfamiliar with the syntax.  In the following code, the `IF` statement is not recognized.
First question, what is the correct syntax of the `IF` statement?  I tried several combinations of arrangements of the quote characters, but have removed them for this example.
Second question, what is the purpose of the `^` at the end of some of the lines?
Third question, what is the purpose of the indent in the lines following the first line?

```
F:\Tools\WinSCP\WinSCP /command="option batch on" ^ "option confirm off" ^ "open WinSCP-ProfileName" ^ 
 "lcd F:\Data\TargetDirectory" ^
 "get ""*_SourceFileName.txt"" %TargetFileName%" ^
 IF %computername%==xxx GOTO LabelElse ^
 "echo do something here" ^
 :LabelElse ^
 "exit" /log=F:\Logs\LogFileName.log
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your whole "batch file" is actually a single WinSCP command-line. It just [broken into multiple physical lines using the `^` and the indentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file#newline_escaping).

You cannot use batch commands (like the `if`) within other command (the WinSCP command-line in this case).

If you need to conditionally modify the commands passed to WinSCP, you either:

- Have to assemble the command-line to a variable upfront, based on your criteria, and then pass it at once to WinSCP.
- Or, more straightforward is to assemble a WinSCP script file instead.

  ```
  set SCRIPT=%TEMP%\winscp.txt

  (
     echo option batch on
     echo option confirm off
     echo open WinSCP-ProfileName
     echo lcd F:\Data\TargetDirectory
     echo get "*_SourceFileName.txt" %TargetFileName%
     IF not %computername%==xxx (
       echo some computer-specific commands here
     )
     echo exit
  ) > %SCRIPT%

  F:\Tools\WinSCP\WinSCP /script=%SCRIPT%  /log=F:\Logs\LogFileName.log
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a template that you'd adjust to suit your needs.

The syntax of the `if` statement is arguably correct, although best practices would have it look like `if "%computername%"=="xxx" goto LabelElse` in case `%computername%` had a space or somehow didn't have a value. The `xxx` bit would be the name of a computer that you don't want to run the `echo do something here` bit on, like some post-processing or something.

The `^` is the escape character in batch, and at the end of a line, it acts as a line continuation character. I suspect that `"option confirm off" ^` and `"open WinSCP-ProfileName" ^` are also meant to be on their own lines. The fact that there's a label as part of the line continuation (`:LabelElse`) is surprising to me, as labels have to be on their own line in order to work. The fact that this is a command being passed to WinSCP may make my concerns irrelevant, but the fact that you're getting an error suggests that this entire thing is coded incorrectly. I'd usually write a separate script for the WinSCP bit and pass that as an argument instead.

The indentations are related to the fact that `^` is a line continuation character and is meant to demonstrate that all of the below lines are related to the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestions here, I got it to work!  What I was really trying to do, was to not delete the file from the sFTP site when executing in Dev or UAT.  Works great!

```
IF %computername%==DevServer GOTO LabelElse
IF %computername%==UatServer GOTO LabelElse
  set "DisplayText=WinSCP command - INCLUDES DELETE from sFTP site - for PRODUCTION"
  set "DeleteOption=-delete"
  GOTO LabelEndif
:LabelElse
  set "DisplayText=WinSCP command - DOES NOT DELETE from sFTP site - for *NON-PROD*"
  set "DeleteOption="
:LabelEndif

rem other stuff here

ECHO %DisplayText%
F:\Tools\WinSCP\WinSCP /command="option batch on" ^ "option confirm off" ^ "open WinSCP-ProfileName" ^ "lcd F:\Data\TargetDirectory" ^
"get %DeleteOption% ""*_SourceFileName.txt"" %TargetFileName%" ^
"exit" /log=F:\Logs\LogFileName.log
```

Comment: Good. Note that the `^` is used in a batch file to escape linebreaks. So it should no be between commands, where you do not break a line. Like between `"option batch on"` and `"option confirm off"` (though these two commands are not really needed anyway, as they are defaults).